# How to use ASP.NET impersonation by controller for LDAP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I've read plenty of SO questions similar to my issue, but nothing that seems to touch all of it at the same time.

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using *Windows Authentication* with the application pool identity set to a dedicated service account. This allows us to use the *WindowsPrincipal* to authenticate the users against our system roles, but have any external systems (i.e., databases) authenticate our application against just the service account.

Everything works fine until we want to push data changes to the user's AD account, as company policy is that we have to do this as the authenticated user, but we obviously don't have users' passwords in order to use the *DirectoryEntry* overload.

In this case, the following returns a valid *DirectoryEntry* instance, but *CommitChanges* throws *UnauthorizedAccessException* "Access is denied". Even though the current Identity (on *Thread.CurrentPrincipal* and the request) are the current user; *ImpersonationLevel* is *Impersonation*.

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + userPath))
{
    de.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = phone;
    de.CommitChanges();
}
```

I've also tried using *HostingEnvironment.Impersonate* and *WindowsIdentity.Impersonate* on the *WindowsIdentity* from the user, but that returns an invalid *DirectoryEntry* with *DirectoryServicesCOMException* "An operations error occurred".

e.g. (not actual code),

```
using (var hei = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate(wi.Token))
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + userPath));
```

and

```
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = wi.Impersonate();
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + userPath));
```

From what I've read, LDAP doesn't support this type of impersonation.

The only way I've been able to make it work (for myself only) is to set the application pool identity to myself, proving that the LDAP code is correct, but getting me no closer to how to authenticate correctly.
I've tried <identity impersonate="true"/> (we normally have it false), but it didn't change anything.

Any guidance would be appreciated, as I'm running out of things to tweak.

---

**Edit for some extra context**

Almost a TL;DR:

This is a new piece of functionality, so the system is working as expected with regards to authenticating users through IIS. We get the valid WindowPrincipal and WindowsIdentity for the user.

Our users have the ability to modify certain fields within AD, such as "telephoneNumber", so we do not have access to (because we shouldn't need) a privileged account with which to make changes to users.
I'm able to make changes to my own AD data if I set everything to myself, but I'm unable to get impersonation to work while the application is running as the service account (or even as anonymous).

Comment: It sounds like you need to give your service account enough permissions to modify user objects within Active Directory? Since normal accounts can't edit other objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, AD will not allow a user to modify Directory Services information, regardless if it's their own account. You'll have to do this with an account that has elevated privileges (I'm not sure about the exact privileges, possibly domain admin).

If you want the users to be able to modify their own directory services properties then you'll have to pass that information along to a service running under elevated privileges.

If this is for authentication then you need to use `LogonUser` to get a token then use `WindowsIdentity` with that token. But remember that to impersonate a user you need a token that hasn't been duplicated. In order to get their username/password you'll need to write a custom Authentication Provider that uses basic authentication over HTTPS. (See `IHttpModule`) and events `AuthenticateRequest` to authenticate and check the WWW-Authenticate header, `EndRequest` to issue the challenge if necessary, `PostRequestHandlerExecute` to modify cookies if necessary.

EDIT: 
If I haven't addressed your issue please let me know. I'm not sure if you're having trouble authenticating the user or modifying their account properties while impersonating the user account.

Also, is your web.config set to

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Comment: Using <identity impersonate="true"/> breaks the app as our database connection is authenticated against a service account, which I do not have the password for; it's set as our ApplicationPool Identity.

Comment: So your Application Pool identity is set to a custom service account and your website is likely then set to pass-through authentication?

Comment: Exactly. I get the authenticated user through as expected, with ImpersonationLevel set to Negotiate.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are having a problem with the impersonation level. I'd think it would have to be set to Impersonation or Delegation. 

I see the following URL may be of some help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079651/impersonation-in-asp-net-web-application-does-not-work-when-running-on-iis

Comment: Just tossing in some additional troubleshooting ideas:

1) Maybe the service account is not allowed to impersonate accounts. See SeImpersonatePrivilege, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821546

2) If you run this code: 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name' it should show you the Name of the Application Pool service account. Really though, we want it to be the account of the impersonated 'WindowsIdentity'. So if it isn't allowing the correct 'ImpersonationLevel' then 'WindowsIdentity'.Impersonate() will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently, and was eventually able to get it to work. The missing piece of the setup is Kerberos Delegation, similar to Scenario 1 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/configure-kerberos-constrained-delegation

*Windows Authentication* and *Negotiate* are terms that actually cover 2 separate auth mechanisms: Kerberos and NTLM. Both are considered "Windows" auth because they use a user's AD credentials for authentication, in a way that does not require sending the plaintext password to the server. Negotiate refers to the fact that the client and server negotiate as to whether to use Kerberos or NTLM. Kerberos is preferred, but requires additional setup in many cases. If that setup has not been performed, NTLM will be used instead. Only Kerberos is capable of the sort of delegation being attempted here, so setting up Kerberos correctly is required.

In short to get this working are the following:

- Set a Service Principal Name of "HTTP/<WebAppHostname>" on your service account in AD
- Configure the service account to be able to delegate authentication to the AD servers. This is done on the Delegation tab of the service account's AD object.

  - It should work to select "Allow delegation to any service"
  - It is more secure to select "Allow delegation to specified services", then select "LDAP/<DomainControllerHostname>" for each domain controller in the environment

Alternatively, if it's acceptable for the web app to use *Basic Authentication* instead, these problems should go away. *WindowsIdentity.Impersonate* should work in that case without any Kerberos setup. Just make sure that you turn *off* Windows auth, in addition to turning on Basic